# Visual Studio Code extension Code Runner invokes 'python -u' instead of 'python3 -u'

Tags: ubuntu, python, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code 1.35.1 installed on Ubuntu 19.04 with python 3.7, extension Python and Code Runner.

If you try running code with Ctrl+Alt+N, then it invokes: 'python -u filename.py'

And it gives the error result: python not found

Settings.json is set to correct path: `"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"`

But default settings is set to `"python"` which is not changeable.

Tried other questions with their solutions, but didn't help.

Is this related with the new version of vscode? How can it be resolved?

Comment: Go to *File > Preferences > Settings* and find *Python Configuration*. This is where you manually change the configurations. Is your configuration listed? Do you have more than one python version installed?

Comment: it's set to /usr/bin/python3. There is only one version installed i.e. 3.7 and Code Runner: Executor Map is also set to /usr/bin/python3 in settings.json. Tried changing it to python3 but no success.

May this is due to new version of vscode? or incompatibility issue? Everything seems set up correctly.

Comment: If VSC cannot be convinced to use `python3`, why don't you add a symbolic link to it named `python`?

Comment: didn't help, it starts complaining no interpreter is selected.

Comment: This question/answer from StackOverflow helped resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986507/unable-to-set-default-python-version-to-python3-in-ubuntu